# Boost autolinks libraries which are not built by Boost, but the intended ones are built

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, boost, static-linking, boost-python

I am developing a Math application which can be extended by writing python scripts.

I am using Qt 4.6.3 (built as static library, debug and release versions) and Boost 1.43.0 (built as static library, runtime-link also set to static, multi-threaded version, debug and release). Everything is built with MSVC++2008. Boost built the following libraries:

- libboost_python-vc90-mt-s-1_43.lib
- libboost_python-vc90-mt-s.lib
- libboost_python-vc90-mt-sgd-1_43.lib
- libboost_python-vc90-mt-sgd.lib

My project compiles, but gives the following error during the linking phase:

```
1>Linking...
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_python-vc90-mt-gd-1_43.lib'
```

Why is it not selecting one of my compiled libraries?

I think the s in the library names stands for static, but then the auto-linking feature seems to select a dynamic library, and I want it all linked statically in one executable.

The same happens with the regex library: I have the same 4 regex libraries compiled and a quick test shows this linking error:

```
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_regex-vc90-mt-gd-1_43.lib'
```

What to do?

Comment: Have you told vc++ where those libraries are located? It's not psychic.

Comment: yes, the library and include paths are set correctly (after checking it 3 times). It just wants filenames that don't exist. But the version of the library that I want is compiled!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is fixed, during the compilation of the boost libraries, I selected the link=static option. Which creates static libraries. I also selected runtime-link=static option, and this was wrong!

The solution for this problem was compiling boost with runtime-link=shared. Now some extra libraries are added, with the correct filenames, so the linker can find them. At first the compiler still searches for the dll library (boost_python-vc90-mt-gd-1_43.lib, instead of libboost_python-vc90-mt-gd-1_43.lib), everything else from boost links automatically to a static library, but because boost.python has a different auto-linkage set up, when you provide BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB, it finally links to the right library and it works!

Answer (score 7):

You can define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB. This prevents automatic linking of boost libraries and you must then link the required boost libs manually.

Answer (score 3):

If 's' stands indeed for static (I don't know all those modifiers by heart), define the BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK symbol while compiling (add it to the command line options). It tells boost to link to the DLL libraries. Alternatively, compile/install static boost libraries.

Comment: but I compiled and installed the boost static libraries, and I want to link to them! I don't want to distribute DLL's with my application.