# Linking to boost::python using Visual C++ Express 10

Tags: c++, python, boost, static-linking

I've built Python (3.2.1) and boost::python (1_47_0) under Windows with Visual C++ Express 2010.  While boost::filesystem works fine, boost::python doesn't (these both require linking to libraries as well as the header).  I'm getting the error:

```
2>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_python-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib'
```

This seems clear enough, but in the stage/lib folder I can see a "libboost_python_vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib" - i.e. the correct filename, but prefixed with "lib".  Somehow the autolinking is working for the filesystem stuff, but not for Python.  If I copy the boost::python lib and remove the "lib" prefix it all links fine.

Is this a known Boost issue, or is something else wrong?  I can rename the files, but it would be nice to remove this step.

Comment: Mistake in your question ? Is your file `libboost_python_vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib` or `libboost_python-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib` ?

Comment: You will get that lib file without "lib" prefix if you build boost as dynamic library (flag `link=shared`). But since you want to do static linking, then the answer to define `STATIC_LIB` below would be more appropriate. Relevant post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3461840/2159806

Comment: @Hans where do you define STATIC_LIB in the CMAKE? In the .h? Can you give an example. I was having trouble choosing which output file to rename boost_python.

Answer (score 4):

You must define `BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB`, if you want to use `libboost_*` libs