# The library file name with "lib" head can't be recognized in codeblocks and vs9 compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost, codeblocks

This environment is win7, codeblocks,vs9,boost1.52,

I have installed boost library with python library.It generates some library files.Such as "libboost_python-vc90-mt-gd-1_52.lib".

Then I write a test code to compile and link.But an error has occurred: can not open file "boost_python-vc90-mt-gd-1_52.lib".

The VS compiler don't recognized a library file name with "lib" head?How to do it better.

Comment: If VS won't add the `lib` automatically, can't you just add it yourself to the lib name in the project?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson,sorry,I don't know how to do.I only work in linux formerly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890146/linking-to-boostpython-using-visual-c-express-10)

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `lib` prefix at the start of the name is a Linux thing. On Windows there is a `.lib` at the end instead.

If the library is named "libboost_python-vc90-mt-gd-1_52", you have to give exactly that name to the linker.

Comment: Just,I give that name to linker.but make the same error.
`link.exe /dll /nologo /LIBPATH:"D:\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib" /LIBPATH:C:\Python27\libs /LIBPATH:D:\boost\lib  /out:bin\Debug\test1.dll user32.lib D:\boost\lib\libboost_python-vc90-mt-gd-1_52.lib  obj\Debug\main.obj   /DEBUG /INCREMENTAL:NO`

Comment: @simon You should probably use only `libboost_python-vc90-mt-gd-1_52.lib` without the full path.

Comment: I have add `D:\boost\lib` to the LIBPATH.I thing that compiler can find it.How to use only `libboost_python-vc90-mt-gd-1_52.lib`?The same as `D:\boost\lib\libboost_python-vc90-mt-gd-1_52.lib` in LIBPATH?I do it too.

Comment: @simon I mean, the directory should be in `LIBPATH` just as it seems to already be, and the library name should not have any path attached (you're linking with `D:\boost\lib\libboost_python-vc90-mt-gd-1_52.lib` which should be only `libboost_python-vc90-mt-gd-1_52.lib`. Kind of like how you set the library path with `-L` in linux and only give the lib name with `-l`. If you use an absolute path with `-l`, it will fail and not find the lib.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Boost uses auto-linking under Windows. Thus, you only need to provide the *location* of the boost libraries, but not the names themselves.

Second, Boost uses different filenames for statically and dynamically linked libraries. The ones with `lib` prefix are for static linking, the ones without for dynamic linking.

By default, Boost uses static linking on Windows. Defining `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` (there are library specific macros as well if you only want to dynamically link certain libraries) will enable dynamic linking.

From your error message, it seems that your project has `BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK` enabled (either in the project settings, as a `#define` or in `<boost/config/user.hpp>`. If you prefer static linking, make sure to change/remove this setting.

Either way, make sure that the respective binaries are available and that their location (just the directory) is known to the linker.