# Error when compiling with boost

Tags: c++, boost, include

I writed project which uses `<boost/thread/locks.hpp>`, i added `include` directory to `Additional Include directories`, and `lib` folder to linker. But when i try to build solution, error:

> Error 1   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc100-mt-sgd-1_50.lib'

I searched this file in lib directory, but no file with this name in lib directory. I found file with similar name  `libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_50`.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I take it you have installed the libraries or built them AND included into your project?

Comment: i built them by guide http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html

Comment: What OS and compiler are you using?

Comment: i use Visual studio 2010 ultimate. Os windows 7 x64

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem seems to be pretty similar to the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460316/boost-autolinks-libraries-which-are-not-build-by-boost-but-the-intented-once-ar). According to the naming conventions described [here](http://www.boost.org/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming) the only difference between the library the linker wants to use and the library you have is that the former links statically to the c++ standard library and the compiler runtime support libraries. I can think of two ways to solve this problem:

1. **Get the library the linker wants**
   a. If you used the boostpro installer:

   > Make sure you check the box for `Multithreaded debug, static runtime` (I would recommend you mark them all)

   b. If you built the library yourself:

   > Open a console window
   >   Change directory to your boost root
   >   The following command builds the required library:
   >   `b2 toolset=msvc-10.0 --with-thread address-model=64 variant=debug link=static runtime-link=static runtime-debugging=on stage`
   >   (I would recommend using:
   >   `b2 toolset=msvc-10.0 address-model=64 --build-type=complete stage`)
2. **Make the linker use the library you want**
   a. Make autolink use the shared libraries

   > You can define BOOST_THREAD_DYN_LINK (to affect only the thread library) or BOOST_ALL_DYN_LIB (to affect all the boost libraries) before the inclusion of the header files (or preferably in your VC project preprocessor settings). This would make the linker try to use the library `boost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_50.lib` (note that the lib- preffix is missing).

   b. Disable autolink

   > You can define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB and then add the exact name of your library in your linker options

Comment: Do you mean to run this:
 1) bootstrap.bat 
2) b2 install --prefix=PREFIX runtime-link=static  
?

Comment: @Eyalk The page linked by Robert in the comments that you seem to be referencing describes the installation of the Boost.Build binaries. In that step you should not add `runtime-link=static`. Once you have Boost.Build installed you need to build the Boost libraries. It's in this step when you would need to add it to your command. I'll try to edit the answer to make this clearer.