# Boost.Build link against boost libraries

Tags: boost, bjam, boost-build

I am trying to link against boost libraries from Jamfile:

```
import os ;
path-constant BOOST_ROOT : [ os.environ BOOST_ROOT ] ;
use-project /boost : $(BOOST_ROOT) ;

exe hello :
            hello.cpp
            /boost//filesystem
            /boost//system
          :
            <link>static
          ;
```

Although I can see from the console output that the libraries are compiled, the linker outputs an error:

```
msvc.link bin\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\hello.exe
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_46.lib'
```

Why there is an error reported? **I AM** linking against the library from the level of Jamfile, so why the library is not linked when it should be? To my understanding, if the entire build process is controlled by Jamfiles, the library should be automatically linked statically, and no compiler-specific flags should be added (as it would made Jamfiles less portable). Please help.

Comment: You are probably having problems with boost's auto link feature. You can disable it by defining `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` (I suppose adding `<define>BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` to the requirements of the target `hello` would suffice).

Comment: wow. seems to work! But how? If I define my own library target:
lib foo : foo.cpp ; and I link against it just like to boost then it works. then why doesn't it work with boost libraries when linking via Jamfiles?

Comment: also please, put this an an answer so I can mark this as Answer and close thread. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably having problems with boost's auto link feature. You can disable it by defining `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` (I suppose adding `<define>BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` to the requirements of the target `hello` would suffice).

Comment: but do you know why it works with custom library marked as target "lib foo : foo.cpp ;" and does not work with boost ?

Comment: @MarcAndreson The problem is specific to the boost libraries. There is some special code in the header files that detects your compiler options and tries to use that information to automatically guess which library must be linked with your program, apparently ignoring any library you add "manually". This process sometimes (frequently? (I don't use Visual Studio)) fails, making the linking harder than it would be without this. There are several questions in SO such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384521/error-when-compiling-with-boost/) with the same problem.